# Использование enum и enum class

Tags: c++, c++11

Оператор `[]` из `std::array` не принимает члены `enum class`. Что лучше: делать `static_cast<size_t>()` или использовать старый `enum` с автоприведением?

Comment: Ответить на вопрос "что лучше" без объяснения задачи затруднительно.

Comment: @user1056837 если так, то покажите плюсы и минусы обоих подходов для вопроса, а я выберу приемлимый вариант для задачи

Comment: @user1056837 я думал, что данный ресурс существует для ответов на вопросы, а не отсылок к документации

Comment: @crstaff ответ на Ваш вопрос зависит от того что Вы вкладываете в понятие "лучше".

Comment: Все должно работать. Приведите конкретный текст ошибки.